# I want to select many data in plot

Tags: r, shiny

global.R code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

data_1 <- read.csv(file = "data_1.csv")
data_2 <- read.csv(file = "data_2.csv")
data_3 <- read.csv(file = "data_3.csv")

data_1$date <- as.Date(data_1$date)
data_2$date <- as.Date(data_2$date)
data_3$date <- as.Date(data_3$date)

total_data <- list(data_1, data_2, data_3)

date_days_1 <- split(data_1, format(as.Date(data_1$date), "%Y-%m"))
date_days_2 <- split(data_2, format(as.Date(data_2$date), "%Y-%m"))
date_days_3 <- split(data_3, format(as.Date(data_3$date), "%Y-%m"))
```

server.R code:

```
itemInput <- reactive({
switch(input$item,
       "data1" = "data_1",
       "data2" = "data_2",
       "data3" = "data_3")
})

productInput <- reactive({
switch(input$select,
       "days" = "total_data",
       "week" = "total_data",
       "season" = "total_data")
})

  output$splitDate <- renderUI({
    if (input$select == "days"){
      selectInput("date_day", "select a month", names(split(data_1, format(as.Date(data_1$date), "%Y-%m"))))
    } else {
      return()
    }
  })

output$chartPlot <- renderPlot({
if(input$select == "days") {
    p <- ggplot(data=data_1,aes(x=date,y=point, group = 1)) + scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "green", "blue")) + xlab("Date") + ylab("Number of people")
  if(input$item == "data1"){
    df <- data.frame(date_days_1[[input$date_day]]) 
    p <- p +geom_line(data = df, size = 1)
  } else if (input$item == "data2"){
    df <- data.frame(date_days_2[[input$date_day]]) 
    p <- p + geom_line(data = df, size = 1)
  } else if (input$item == "data3"){
    df <- data.frame(date_days_3[[input$date_day]]) 
    p <- p + geom_line(data = df, size = 1)
  } else {
    return()
  }
} else {
  return()
}

print(p)

#plot(as.Date(df$date),df$point)
```

})

ui.R code:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
navbarPage("Plot",
         tabPanel("lineChart",
                  sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                      #add choices
                      selectizeInput("item", "select item:",
                                     choices = c("data1", "data2", "data3")
                                     ,multiple = TRUE),
                      selectInput("select", "select time:",
                                  choices = c("days", "week", "season")),
                      uiOutput("splitDate")
                    ),

                    mainPanel(
                      #plotOutput("chartPlot")
                      plotOutput("chartPlot",width=800,height=600)
                    )
                  )
         )
  )
))
```

There are data like link: [data1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3qxdqbFrqZNOHJzVXRLWGlhR0k) [data2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3qxdqbFrqZNRlR6Sm55SUlwNTA) [data3](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3qxdqbFrqZNa2tSUTZSRHZEamc)

I want to select many data in plot.

I select two data in plot, but appear this error message:

> Warning in if (input$item == "data1") { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

How to fix it?

Comment: Try `if (input$item %in% "data1") {`

Comment: @PorkChop I have tried ,but not working.

Comment: Did you change all `==` to `%in%`?

Comment: @PorkChop Yes, but not work. select first data not any plot, but select second data only appear one line.

Comment: I will need a fully reproducible example, which I can simply `copy` and `paste` into my `rstudio` and recreate your issue. As you have data named `data_1` etc I need those too. Otherwise we will not move as fast to solve your issue.

Comment: @PorkChop Ok. I have edited my question. There are my all R code. Thank you.

Comment: In `output$splitDate`

Comment: Its not 100% clear to me, do you want all of them in one plot if `data1` `data2` and `data3` selected or you just want 1 of them at the time?

Comment: First, I want to select month.
Second, I want all of them in one plot and user can select hi want data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, please review the answer below

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

data_1 <- read.csv(file = "data_1.csv")
data_2 <- read.csv(file = "data_2.csv")
data_3 <- read.csv(file = "data_3.csv")

data_1$date <- as.Date(data_1$date)
data_2$date <- as.Date(data_2$date)
data_3$date <- as.Date(data_3$date)

total_data <- list(data_1, data_2, data_3)

date_days_1 <- split(data_1, format(as.Date(data_1$date), "%Y-%m"))
date_days_2 <- split(data_2, format(as.Date(data_2$date), "%Y-%m"))
date_days_3 <- split(data_3, format(as.Date(data_3$date), "%Y-%m"))


ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Plot",
             tabPanel("lineChart",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          #add choices
                          selectizeInput("item", "select item:",choices = c("data1", "data2", "data3"),multiple = TRUE),
                          selectInput("select", "select time:",choices = c("days", "week", "season")),
                          uiOutput("splitDate")
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          #plotOutput("chartPlot")
                          plotOutput("chartPlot",width=800,height=600)
                        )
                      )
             )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {

  itemInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$item,"data1" = "data_1","data2" = "data_2","data3" = "data_3")
  })

  productInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$select,
           "days" = "total_data",
           "week" = "total_data",
           "season" = "total_data")
  })

  output$splitDate <- renderUI({
    if (input$select == "days"){
      selectInput("date_day", "select a month", names(split(data_1, format(as.Date(data_1$date), "%Y-%m"))))
    } else {
      return()
    }
  })

  output$chartPlot <- renderPlot({
    if(is.null(input$item)){return(NULL)}
    if(input$select %in% "days") {
      p <- ggplot(data=data_1,aes(x=date,y=point, group = 1)) + scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "green", "blue")) + xlab("Date") + ylab("Number of people")
      df <- data.frame(date_days_1[[input$date_day]]) 
      df2 <- data.frame(date_days_2[[input$date_day]]) 
      df3 <- data.frame(date_days_3[[input$date_day]]) 

      if(any(input$item  %in% "data1")){
        p <- p +geom_line(data = df, size = 1, color='green')
      } 
      if (any(input$item  %in% "data2")){
        p <- p +geom_line(data = df2, size = 1)
      } 
      if (any(input$item  %in% "data3")){
        p <- p +geom_line(data = df3, size = 1, color='red')
      }
    } else {
      return(NULL)
    }

    print(p)
  })

}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! I have corrected my code. It can work!! Thank you very much.